# Existing ways to set component's UI style for Android Library Module?

Tags: android, android-layout

*P.S.: Just to be clear, I would like to use the style defined on Style file in order to achieve the proposed scenario*

I'm currently developing a [library](https://github.com/edsilfer/android-search-interface) that will provide a simple search interface for Android users. I want to build it as flexible as possible allowing these types of configurations:

```
data class SearchPallet(
        val searchBar: SearchBar,
        val resultRow: ResultRow,
        val resultDisclaimer: ResultDisclaimer,
        val background: Background
) : Serializable {

    data class SearchBar(
            val inputStyle: Int,
            val color: Int,
            val iconBack: Int,
            val iconClear: Int
    ) : Serializable

    data class ResultRow(
            val thumbnailStyle: ThumbnailStyle,
            val headerStyle: Int,
            val subHeader1Style: Int,
            val subHeader2Style: Int,
            val color: Int
    ) : Serializable

    data class ResultDisclaimer(
            val messageStyle: Int,
            val color: Int
    ) : Serializable

    data class Background(
            val color: Int,
            val drawable: Int = -1,
            val alpha: Float = 1.toFloat()
    ) : Serializable
}
```

*code written using Kotlin language*

Ideally, I wanted the client to set a style element in its resources and pass it forward so I could attach it to the UI component but, unfortunately, **it seems that this is not yet support by Android SDK**. ***What would be the possible (and most elegant) ways for transferring resource configuration to the library module?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set the theme/style for a given component if it is added programmatically.